# how to split one list value to elements

Tags: java, java-8

How to get elements from the below list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> getRoles = 
buildRolesList(list, role).stream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .map(str->str.replace ( "[","" ))
    .map(str->str.replace ( "]","" ))
    .collect( Collectors.toCollection ( ArrayList::new ) );
```

`getRoles = "[admin, user]"` ---this is the list I am getting, but the list wanted is `["admin","user"]` splitted

How to achieve the list values as `[0--->"admin",1--->"user"]`

The above result is coming in size 1 but wanted it to be size 2

Comment: I don't see any attempt at splitting. Are you looking for the `String.split()` method?

Comment: yes not sure how to split as splitting is coming as "[admin", "user]"

Comment: To clarify your question, `getRoles` is a list of comma-separated strings, each of which you'd like to expand into one list, one value per index?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem.

Comment: @Gojo, can you provide the `buildRolesList` method?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of strings like `"[admin, user]"`. Then you do it almost right, just forget to split a string to individual roles.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("[admin, user]",
                                "[owner, developer]");

    Set<String> roles = getRoles(list);
    System.out.println(roles);  // [owner, admin, developer, user]
}

public static Set<String> getRoles(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .map(String::toLowerCase)
               .map(Foo::getRoles)
               .flatMap(Set::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private static Set<String> getRoles(String str) {
    return Stream.of(str)
                 .map(s -> s.replace("[", ""))
                 .map(s -> s.replace("]", ""))
                 .map(s -> s.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                 .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to split one list value to elements

It looks like you have a list of roles in pairs and want to break that up into separate lists of size 2. `List.toString()` So can't you instead return a `List<String>` of all the roles and just copy in pairs.  Here is how it would work.

```
List<List<String>> roles = List.of("admin", "user", 
                                   "steno","typist"));

List<List<String>> roleLists = new ArrayList<>();

if (roles.size()%2 != 0) {
     System.out.println("Roles must be in pairs");
} else {
     for (int i = 0; i < roles.size(); i+=2) {
        roleLists.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(roles.get(i),roles.get(i+1))));
     }
}
```

Then when you get the list of lists you can retrieve the values as follows:

```
for(List<String> lst : roles) {
    System.out.println("List -> " + lst);
    for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
         System.out.printf("   %d -> %s%n", i, lst.get(i));
    }
}
```

prints

```
List -> [admin, user]
   0 -> admin
   1 -> user
List -> [steno, typist]
   0 -> steno
   1 -> typist
```

Otherwise, just do the following:

```
String s = "[admin, user]";

String[] result = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s+]+","").split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d -> %s%n", i, result[i]);
}
```

prints

```
0 -> admin
1 -> user
```